# How to write values to NFC tag from two activities without overwriting existing values?

Tags: java, android, nfc, overwrite, ndef

I am trying to write an Android application that has two activities which write multiple values (Strings/text) to the same NFC tag. I have managed to make one activity to write values to a tag, but how do I prevent the second activity from overwriting the values of the first activity?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
ToggleButton tglReadWrite;
Button anotherActivtybtn;
EditText txtName;
EditText txtCountry;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    tglReadWrite = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tglReadWrite);
    txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idName);
    txtCountry= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idCountry);
    anotherActivtybtn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.anotherActivtybtn);

    anotherActivtybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(nfcAdapter !=null){

        /* go to phone's nfc settings */
        if(!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()){
            showNfcSettings();
        }
        enableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    }

}

private void showNfcSettings() {
    Intent nfcSettingIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(nfcSettingIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    disableForegroundDispatchSystem();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NfcIntent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(tglReadWrite.isChecked())
        {
            Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

            if(parcelables != null && parcelables.length > 0)
            {
                readTextFromMessage((NdefMessage) parcelables[0]);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "No NDEF messages found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else{
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            NdefMessage ndefMessage = createNdefMessage(txtName.getText().toString(), txtCountry.getText().toString());

            writeNdefMessage(tag, ndefMessage);
        }

    }
}

private void readTextFromMessage(NdefMessage ndefMessage) {
    NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = ndefMessage.getRecords();

    if(ndefRecords != null && ndefRecords.length>0){

        NdefRecord ndefRecord = ndefRecords[0];
        NdefRecord ndefRecord2 = ndefRecords[1];

        String tagContent = getTextFromNdefRecord(ndefRecord);
        String tagContent2 = getTextFromNdefRecord(ndefRecord2);

        txtName.setText(tagContent);
        txtCountry.setText(tagContent2);

    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No NDEF records found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private void enableForegroundDispatchSystem() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    IntentFilter[] intentFilters = new IntentFilter[]{};

    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFilters, null);
}

private void disableForegroundDispatchSystem() {
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

private void formatTag(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage) {
    try {
        NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);

        if (ndefFormatable == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag is not ndef formatable!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else{
            ndefFormatable.connect();
            ndefFormatable.format(ndefMessage);
            ndefFormatable.close();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag writen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("formatTag", e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void writeNdefMessage(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage) {
    try {

        if (tag == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag object cannot be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);

        if (ndef == null) {
            // format tag with the ndef format and writes the message.
            formatTag(tag, ndefMessage);
        } else {
            ndef.connect();
            if (!ndef.isWritable()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Tag is not writable!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ndef.close();
                return;
            }

            ndef.writeNdefMessage(ndefMessage);
            ndef.close();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag writen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("writeNdefMessage", e.getMessage());
    }

}

private NdefRecord createTextRecord(String content) {
    try {
        byte[] language;
        language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().getBytes("UTF-8");

        final byte[] text = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
        final int languageSize = language.length;
        final int textLength = text.length;
        final ByteArrayOutputStream payload = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1 + languageSize + textLength);

        payload.write((byte) (languageSize & 0x1F));
        payload.write(language, 0, languageSize);
        payload.write(text, 0, textLength);

        return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload.toByteArray());

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("createTextRecord", e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

private NdefMessage createNdefMessage(String content, String content2) {

    NdefRecord ndefRecord = createTextRecord(content);
    NdefRecord ndefRecord2 = createTextRecord(content2);

    NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{ndefRecord, ndefRecord2});

    return ndefMessage;
}

public void tglReadWriteOnClick(View view){
    txtName.setText("");
    txtCountry.setText("");
}

public String getTextFromNdefRecord(NdefRecord ndefRecord)
{
    String tagContent = null;
    try {
        byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
        int languageSize = payload[0] & 0063;
        tagContent = new String(payload, languageSize + 1,
                payload.length - languageSize - 1, textEncoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("getTextFromNdefRecord", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return tagContent;
}
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An NFC Forum type tag can only contain one NDEF message. Consequently, the method `ndef.writeNdefMessage(ndefMessage)` will always overwrite any existing NDEF message with the new message passed as the argument `ndefMessage`.

That NDEF message may, of course, consist of as many NDEF records as you like (or actually as fit on your tag).

If you would like to preserve exisiting data, you would therefore need to read the existing NDEF message first, e.g. by

```
Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
if (parcelables != null && parcelables.length > 0) {
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = (NdefMessage)parcelables[0];
    ...
```

You could then parse this message and keep/drop the parts (NDEF records or data elements) that you would like to preserve/remove. Finally, you would add your new parts to that message and write the whole message to the tag again.

Comment: if I understood correctly, I can write multiple records inside a NDEF message from only one activity, since it is not still possible to write to tag with new information from another activity since only one NDEF message can be written to the tag

Comment: @DaGuy On Android, only one activity (the foreground activity) as access to NFC tags are any time. So if you want to keep the data that you previously stored on the tag (using another activity), the second activity needs to read the data, add its own data and store everyting again on the tag. You can fit as many records as you want on a single tag (as long as there is sufficient storage space available).

Comment: can I avoid reading what the first activity has written to the tag and write new information to the tag from the second activity?

Comment: I will explain in details what I am trying to do. I have 2 activities (can read and write) where both have the same code, the first activity write a person name and country while the second activity writes person interests and hobbies. After the first activity has written the information to the tag, the information can be read by both activities and the information gets overwritten by the second activity (when I write persons interests and hobbies)

Comment: @DaGuy What's the problem with reading the old data before writing the new data? All of that happens in a single tap anyways. Overall, I'm not sure I understand why you would even want to write data from both activities. It seems to me that the user is going to pass through both activities anyways (writing both datasets to the tag). If that's the case, it would probably be better to pass the information from the first activity to the second one and only write the aggregated dataset to the tag from the second activity.

Comment: @MichaelRoland I am very aware about competence in NFC, but in this case your statement is wrong. One NFC Tag CAN contain multiple records. That is by the way the only chance to have some "formatting" when having multiple Text Records. It can even have multiple messages. But Android only reads the first message.

Comment: @ErikM I never wrote that a tag could not contain multiple NDEF **records**. I clearly wrote that an NFC tag (at least following the NFC Forum tag specifications) can only contain one NDEF **message**. I've updated my answer to make that even clearer (and to reflect what I wrote in my comments above).